# Extracting items from list into grouped and nested lists

Tags: python, list

I have a list like this:

```
FULL_DATA = ['LIN+++1234:BP', 'PIA+1+PRODUCT 1',  'QTY+113:10:PCE', 'SCC+4', 'DTM+2:20200506:102', 'QTY+113:14:PCE', 'SCC+4', 'DTM+2:20190513:102', 'LIN+++5=5678:BP', 'PIA+1+PRODUCT 2', 'QTY+113:19:PCE', 'SCC+4', 'DTM+2:20190520:102', 'QTY+113:13:PCE', 'SCC+4', 'DTM+2:20190527:102']
```

This extract is just the short version of the actual list which contains dozens of repeating LIN entries.

My current approach was to extract the index of the 'PIA' and 'QTY' tags and building pairs with the next occurrence. Subsequently looping through those start and end limits and building a new nested sublist.

Since the 'PIA' tag can occur multiple times in a file, the best approach is to use the 'LIN' tag.

This seems clunky and I am looking for a more elegant solution to retrieve an output as such:

```
PRODUCT_1 = [['QTY+113:10:PCE', 'SCC+4', 'DTM+2:20200506:102'], ['QTY+113:14:PCE', 'SCC+4', 'DTM+2:20190513:102']]
PRODUCT_2 = [['QTY+113:19:PCE', 'SCC+4', 'DTM+2:20190520:102'], ['QTY+113:13:PCE', 'SCC+4', 'DTM+2:20190527:102']]
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Just as an FYI, if you're using variables like `foo_1`, `foo_2`... `foo_n` consider using a list or dict. Without showing your current code, it's hard to determine what more elegant should look like.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I was looking for a clean start, as my version started to get very entangled, thus I did not add my code here.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert this list to a dictionary using a simple approach as

```
i = 0
m = dict()
while i < len(FULL_DATA):
    if FULL_DATA[i][:3] == "LIN":
        product = FULL_DATA[i + 1]
        i += 2
        while i < len(FULL_DATA) and FULL_DATA[i][:3] != 'LIN':
            entries = m.get(product, [])
            entries.append(FULL_DATA[i:i + 3])
            m[product] = entries
            i += 3

for key in m:
    print(key, m[key])
```

This works based on the assumption that after each LIN there would be a product followed by `k*3` entries of product details. That makes it very simple, you run two while loop one for the product-related entries while other that checks for next LIN.

Comment: Thank you ! This works fine with most of the files I got. There are two exceptions though where before the LIN tag, there might be some other tags. Apologies that I did not mention it before. Secondly, in rare cases there might be a second PIA tag behind the first PIA, such as PRODUCT 1 DETAILS.

Answer (score 0):

may this will work for you.

```
    FULL_DATA = ['LIN+++1234:BP', 'PIA+1+PRODUCT 1', 'QTY+113:10:PCE', 'SCC+4', 'DTM+2:20200506:102', 'QTY+113:14:PCE', 'SCC+4', 'DTM+2:20190513:102', 'LIN+++5=5678:BP', 'PIA+1+PRODUCT 2', 'QTY+113:19:PCE', 'SCC+4', 'DTM+2:20190520:102', 'QTY+113:13:PCE', 'SCC+4', 'DTM+2:20190527:102']


    products = []
    buffer = []
    for item in FULL_DATA:
        if not item.startswith(r'LIN+++') and not item.startswith(r'PIA+'):
            buffer.append(item)
            if len(buffer) == 3:
                products[-1].append(buffer)
                buffer = []
        elif len(products) == 0 or len(products[-1]) > 0: # avoid append [] twice
            products.append([])

    print(products)
```